# Orchard - How to show all blog posts with a specific tag as a widget

Tags: tags, widget, orchardcms

I have a product **contentType** to which I've created several **products** (product1, product2, etc..).

I also have a **blog** in which I've posted several **posts**.  Some of the posts are **tagged** with "product1"

When i go to the detail page for product1 (~/product1) I'd like to **list the posts that have been tagged with product1**.  I'd like to do this in widget.

Bonus: How to create a widget that displays all content tagged with the **last segment of current url**.  So when I'm on ~/product1 it display product1 tagged content and when I'm on ~/foo it displays foo tagged content.

Note:  The Vandalay Tag cloud module has a feature very close to this.  If rss feeds are enabled, you can navigate to something like "http://localhost:4423/rss?tag=product1" and you get the content I'm looking for as a page, but I need to add that content to the product1 page.

Comment: You need to take a look at your `Layer` as this is where you'll define your rules.

Comment: @neil - Yes, layer is logical place to do it but I need a widget to stick in the layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tony Johnson has a great series on Orchard and part 7 covers this exact scenario. http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/06/real-world-orchard-cmspart-7finding.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually the list of items under a specific tags is not provided by the tagcloud module but by the Orchard.Tags module. It should be fairly easy to build a widget that does exactly what you want, starting from ITagService. For example, the driver for the widget's part could look at route values and get the tag name to look for, then query the tag service to get the tag and then the items associated with it. Generate a list shape with those items and you're pretty much done. Makes sense?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the route I've been going down for the past few hours.  Not without a couple of false leads but I was headed there.  Thanks for the help!  I'll post the widget code when I get it working.